# Remmina RDP connection from Bash without encrypting password or creating profiles?

Tags: bash, encryption, rdp, remmina

How can I connect to a machine via RDP using Remmina?
I understand that I can do:

```
remmina -c "rdp://Administrator@192.168.122.2"
```

But then I have to enter the password which I don't want to do.

Remmina does appear to support this format as well:

```
remmina -c rdp://username:encrypted-password@server
```

But my Bash script needs to be fully automated and I couldn't find a way to encrypt the password without interaction. Besides that, the password encryption seems to rely on other system services that I'm not even sure are necessarily available. When I run `remmina --encrypt-password` for the first time, it just prints this message:

```
Load modules from /usr/lib64/remmina/plugins
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
The glibsecret secret plugin  has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin
```

instead of letting encrypt a password.

I'd also like to avoid generating a profile just for that.

Encrypting the password doesn't benefit me in any way btw because this is just for a local connection to an unimportant virtual machine. The only reason I'm even using a password is that Windows doesn't allow password-less RDP.

**Edit:**

The best I was able to come up with so far is:

```
RDP_USER=Administrator
RDP_PASSWORD=admin
RDP_HOST=192.168.122.2

# Run it once because the first time it prints a useless message instead of actually encrypting
echo "$RDP_PASSWORD" | remmina --encrypt-password &>/dev/null

# Run it again, hoping it always works the second time
ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD="$(echo "$RDP_PASSWORD" | remmina --encrypt-password | grep 'Encrypted password: ' | cut -d':' -f2- | tr -d ' ')"

remmina -c "rdp://${RDP_USER}:${ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD}@${RDP_HOST}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remmina uses DBUS to communicate with the other instances, which are running according to your description (check application tray).
Try running it in a separate session:

```
dbus-run-session remmina --encrypt-password <<< "password"
```

or even disconnected from DBUS:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= remmina --encrypt-password <<< "password"
```

You also can do it with openssl without the need to run graphical environment. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398788/287403).

Comment: I get this following error "Unknown option --encrypt-password"